# non-static reference member ‘int& Property<int>::value’, can’t use default assignment operator

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, reference

In some C++ code, I am encountering a compile-time error that seems like it might be indicating that I am trying to reseat a reference. But I feel quite sure that I am not trying to reseat a reference. I do not understand the cause of the error. Perhaps I am being silly, and missing something obvious. Or perhaps the problem reflects deep principles of C++ template programming that I do not adequately understand. Either way, I hope some of you can help. This is the code:

```
// p.cpp - slimmed down demonstration of error in prop.cpp

template<class T>
class Property {
protected:
    T& value;

public:
    explicit Property(T& a) : value(a) { }

    // default "copy" setter
    virtual Property<T>& operator=(T a) { value = a; return *this; }

    // default "copy" getter
    virtual operator T() const { return value; }

    template<class U> // must invoke U virtual getter and T virtual setter
    Property<T>& operator=(const Property<U>& newval)
        { return (*this = U(newval)); }

    /* // uncommenting this eliminates the error
    Property<T>& operator=(const Property<T>& newval)
        { return (*this = T(newval)); }
    /**/
};

int main()
{
    //* // this code produces the error
    {
        int i_ = 10, j_;
        Property<int> i (i_), j (j_);
        j = i;
    }
    /**/

    /* // this code does NOT produce the error
    {
        int i_ = 10;
        long j_;
        Property<int> i (i_);
        Property<long> j (j_);
        j = i;
    }
    /**/

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this with `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1` using the command `g++ -o p p.cpp` I get this output:

```
p.cpp: In member function ‘Property<int>& Property<int>::operator=(const Property<int>&)’:
p.cpp:4:7: error: non-static reference member ‘int& Property<int>::value’, can’t use default assignment operator
p.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
p.cpp:33:13: note: synthesized method ‘Property<int>& Property<int>::operator=(const Property<int>&)’ first required here
```

Before you tell me that I am trying to reseat a reference, please keep in mind that:

1. Uncommenting the definition for `Property::operator=` that explicitly takes the same constructed type on the right side as the constructed type on the left side eliminates the error. So the problem is not, per se, that `Property<int>::value` is being accessed through `*this`.
2. Independently, as shown in `main()`, the `operator=` method template inside the `Property` class template is instantiated and works fine when the data type of the value on the right side of `=` is different from the data type on the left side of `=`.
3. `value` is a reference, but there is nothing wrong with assigning a value to it with `=`, at least in general. It is non-`const`. So once it is instantiated (which is guaranteed, via the initialization list in `Property`'s only constructor), assigning a value to it does not attempt to reseat it, but instead assigns a new value to the memory location to which it refers.

I will provide the larger file `prop.cpp` which contains (successful) unit tests for each of `Property`'s member functions, *if requested*.

You may notice that this code is an attempt to (partially) implement "function-like" ("C#-style") properties in C++. But this question is not about whether or not it would actually be appropriate to do this a real-world C++ project, nor is it about whether or not the pattern I have chosen is the most appropriate. It's possible that I'll ask separate questions about that later. If you want to comment on or criticize my approach, I *am* interested. **I only ask that you not do it here, because it would distract from the more specific purpose of this question.** Instead, you could post your own question, possibly with your own answer, and post a brief comment here linking to your new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the compiler said, non-static reference cannot be assigned using the compiler-generated assignment operator. A user-defined copy assignment operator is required.

Your user-defined assignment operator performs assignment to the object referenced by `value`, by calling first your `operator T()` to obtain a temporary value of type `T` and then your `Property<T>& operator=(T a)` to execute `value = a`, which replaces the referenced-to object with the value obtained from the conversion operator.

If nothing is derived from your class, your operator= is equivalent to

```
// uncommenting this eliminates the error
Property<T>& operator=(const Property<T>& newval)
    {
//          return (*this = T(newval)); // convert to T, then assign
            value = newval.value;       // assign the referenced object
            return *this;
    }
```

Comment: Why does `template<class U> Property<T>& Property<T>::operator=(const Property<U>&)` work when `U` is a different type from `T`? And why does the specialization `Property<T>& Property<T>::operator=(const Property<T>&)` work? And why does `Property<T>& Property<T>::operator=(T)` work? All of them assign to `T& Property<T>::value`. None uses a user-defined `operator=` that takes a `T&` on the left-hand side. What is different? Why does it **only** fail to work when I try to call the generic `=` for assigning a `const Property<U>&` to a `Property<T>&` with both arguments of type `Property<T>`?

Comment: @EliahKagan The answer to each of these questions is "because it is selected by overload resolution". Non-template member functions (like the compiler-generated copy assignment operator) are considered before template instantiations.

Comment: Thanks much! That is what I did not understand--I did not realize that `Property<T>`'s implicit default assignment operator was being considered in overload resolution before the instantiation of `template<class U> Property<int>& Property<int>::operator=(const Property<U>&)` with `int` as `U`. Is there a way to fix this problem without duplicating the code in `template<class U> Property<T>& Property<T>::operator=(const Property<U>&)` (i.e., without defining `Property<T>& Property<T>::operator=(const Property<T>&)`)?

Comment: @Ellah: Your real copy assignment operator could just redirect to the templated one: `Property& operator=(Property const& other){ return operator=<>(other); }`. Operators are still ordinary functions after all, and can be called as such. The `<>` behind the name will make the compiler consider only templates so you get no infinite recursion. Or (I prefer this), just make a member function called `assign` that does the job, maybe virtual even and let the assignment operators non-virtual.

Answer (score 0):

The second case seems a little clearer: The user provided assignment operator is used.

```
{ U u = U(newval); // extract a value
  *this = u; // use the custom assignment operator that takes a 
             // value as an argument and assigns to a reference
}
```

The first case is different: The user defined assignment operator is not picked and the compiler tries to synthesize it. This is not possible for non-static references and hence the program is ill-formed.

Comment: Assigning an `int` to an `int` is also perfectly legal. What distinguishes the second case in `main()` from the first? In the first case, I attempt to assign a `Property<int>` to a `Property<int>`, and that fails. In the second case, I attempt to assign a `Property<int>` to a `Property<long>`, and that succeeds. Why is a user-defined assignment operator only needed for assigning a `Property<T>` to a `Property<T>`, but not for assigning a `Property<U>` to a `Property<T>` where `U` is a different type from `T`?

Comment: @EliahKagan Sorry, my brain was not working properly. This should be fixed now. Maybe you should remember that reseating a reference means to try to make it refer to another object. Assigning to a reference simply assigns to the referent.

Comment: I had not understood why the user-defined assignment operator was not selected for assigning a `Property<U>` to a `Property<T>` when `U` is the same type as `T`. Cubbi's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8631219/1038860) clarified this (in the comments) for me. I now understand that it is because overload resolution considers the implicit copy assignment operator before any template instantiation. (By the way, my confusion was not related to my use of "reseat." Searching for the error, other posts I'd found were related to attempts to change what object a reference referred to.)